# Strange SequenceType behaviour when using a wrapper

Tags: swift

I have a wrapper that wraps a sequence:

```
struct SequenceWrapper<T>: SequenceType {
    var sequence: AnySequence<T>

    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<T> {
        return sequence.generate()
    }
}

let wrapper = SequenceWrapper(sequence: AnySequence(1 ... 10))
```

If I make two generators and call `next()` on both, nothing strange happens:

```
let generator = wrapper.generate()
let another = wrapper.generate()

generator.next() // 1
another.next()   // 1
```

So far, so good. However, if I first call `dropFirst()` on my wrapper, I get strange behaviour:

```
let wrapper = SequenceWrapper(sequence: AnySequence(1 ... 10))
let trimmed = wrapper.dropFirst()

let generator = trimmed.generate()
let another = trimmed.generate()

generator.next() // 2
another.next()   // 3, huh?
```

If I use `dropLast()` instead of `dropFirst()`, the outputs are `1` and `1`, as expected.

If I don't use the wrapper `struct` I made, but a direct `AnySequence` instance instead, nothing out of the ordinary happens:

```
let sequence = AnySequence(1 ... 10)
let trimmed = sequence.dropFirst()

let generator = trimmed.generate()
let another = trimmed.generate()

generator.next() // 2
another.next()   // 2, as expected
```

I can't make any sense of this. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to debug through the behavior to understand the specific behavior, but this most likely happens because `SequenceType` is [not required to be iterable multiple times](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/SequenceType/).

> `SequenceType` makes no requirement on conforming types regarding
>   whether they will be destructively "consumed" by iteration. To ensure
>   non-destructive iteration, constrain your sequence to `CollectionType`.
>
> As a consequence, it is not possible to run multiple for loops on a sequence to "resume" iteration:
>
> ```
> for element in sequence {
>   if ... some condition { break }
> }
>
> for element in sequence {
>   // Not guaranteed to continue from the next element.
>   // [mine: not guaranteed to restart from the beginning either]
> }
> ```
>
> `SequenceType` makes no requirement about the behavior in that case. It
>   is not correct to assume that a sequence will either be "consumable"
>   and will resume iteration, or that a sequence is a collection and will
>   restart iteration from the first element. A conforming sequence that
>   is not a collection is allowed to produce an arbitrary sequence of
>   elements from the second generator.

In other words, the two generators that you get from calling `generate()` twice are not guaranteed to not interfere with one another. In fact, it's legal for a type to implement both `SequenceType` and `GeneratorType` and implement `generate()` as `return self`. Any shared state (from member references, or if the sequence itself is a reference type) will be shared across generators, which is why you should only make one.

Comment: That explains a lot. It seems like an unnecessary restriction, but they probably had good reasons for it. However, `trimmed` and another` were both declared with `let`, so doesn't this break the contract that value types declared with `let` are never mutated?

Comment: @TimVermeulen, if the generator is not a value type, or if the value type keeps its state behind a reference type, let won't prevent it. As for why it's "restricted" that way, it's to allow a type to be both a sequence and a generator instead of having to create a distinct type for the sequence and the generator.

Comment: The generator is a value type. Its state is probably inside a reference type, but that is an implementation detail. The compiler may not do anything to prevent it, but I think it's very misleading nonetheless. :P

Answer (score 0):

The internal `dropFirst()` method returns a new instance of AnySequence (as you can see in this line: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#l1070).

What you need to add to your `SequenceWrapper` are these lines:

```
func dropFirst() -> SequenceWrapper.SubSequence {
    return sequence.dropFirst()
}
```

Here is a short Playground snippet for testing:

```
struct SequenceWrapper<T>: SequenceType {
    var sequence: AnySequence<T>

    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<T> {
        return sequence.generate()
    }

    func dropFirst() -> SequenceWrapper.SubSequence {
        return sequence.dropFirst()
    }
}

let wrapper = SequenceWrapper(sequence: AnySequence(1 ... 10))
var generator = wrapper.generate()
var another = wrapper.generate()

generator.next() // 1
another.next()   // 1

var trimmed = wrapper.dropFirst()

generator = trimmed.generate()
another = trimmed.generate()

generator.next() // 2
another.next() // 2! :)
```